# Combined FaceBook client and server side authenticaion

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-java-api

I have the following use case

1. My application on iOS is using the FaceBook iOS SDK to authenticate with FB
2. The application then make a REST call over https to my server to register the FB account to their service account (the service I am offering)

In step 2 the client is sending the FaceBook UID.

My problem is that the server has no FB integration so has to reply on the client sending the right FaceBook UID.

So the problem is obvious, a hacker can attach someone else FaceBook account to their service account .

What I would like is for the server (Java) to be able to validate that the user who is sending the request owns the Facebook UID in question.

I have been searching online and cannot find anything that I think will work.

I came across a vague post about using the FB `signedRequest` field, this could be passed to the server to validate the user.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thought:

Once you authenticate the user in your iOS app, get the `access_token`, and pass only this in your REST call to your server.

On the server side, make a request to `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...` using the `access_token` that you transmitted. If the access token is valid, you will get all the the user's data proving that you have a valid, authenticated user.

If you wanted to be extra sure, you can also request `http://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=...` to be sure that the access token was created by your app.